# Postgresql how handle json array with select query to attribute wise in table?

Tags: postgresql

```
[
  {
    "passengerId": "RGR",
    "passengerFirstName": "",
    "passengerLastName": "",
    "passengerPaxType": "",
    "passengerBasicFare": 0,
    "passengerTotalTax": 0,
    "passengerTransactionAmount": 0,
    "otherCharges": [
      {
        "passengerId": "RGR",
        "chargeCodeAndType": "",
        "chargeAmount": 0,
        "passengerid": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "passengerId": "Test",
    "passengerFirstName": "",
    "passengerLastName": "",
    "passengerPaxType": "",
    "passengerBasicFare": 0,
    "passengerTotalTax": 0,
    "passengerTransactionAmount": 0,
    "otherCharges": [
      {
        "passengerId": "Test",
        "chargeCodeAndType": "",
        "chargeAmount": 0,
        "passengerid": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

please find above JSON payload I need to select only nested array object- "otherCharges" with select query

```
"passengerId": "Test",
"chargeCodeAndType": "",
"chargeAmount": 0,
```

as column. I tried a lot with PostgreSQL.

Comment: So you want a result with three columns and as many rows as there are elements in the array? Why don't you want `"passengerId": "RGR"` in the result?

Comment: Yeah, i need all only parameter associate with otherCharges attributes from all the json array object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand what exactly the output is you want.

But maybe something like this?

```
select i.item ->> 'passengerId' as passenger_id, 
       i.item ->> 'chargeCodeAndType' as charge_code,
       (i.item ->> 'chargeAmount')::numeric as amount
from the_table tt
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(tt.the_column) as x(element)
  cross join jsonb_array_element(x.element -> 'otherCharges') as i(item)
```